# Time to obtain Italian spouse visa?

Tags: visa, eu-spouses, italy, pakistani-citizen

If one marries an italian citizen how much time does it take for the spouse to join him in Italy ?
The spouse needs a visa to visit Italy.

Comment: Are you referring solely to the visa or to the entire process including the Nulla Osta authorisation? Which province will you be applying to? According to https://visaguide.world/europe/italy-visa/long-stay/family/ the end-to-end process can take up to 1 year in total

Comment: I am talking about total process

Comment: @Traveller that page only applies to family members who are joining non-EU citizens in Italy.

Answer (score 1):

The spouse of an Italian citizen is [entitled to a simplified visa application procedure that is free of charge](https://vistoperitalia.esteri.it/Moduli/en/Informativa%20familiari%20UE.pdf):

> The documents that family members of an EU citizen need to submit when applying for a visa are listed in the above art. 2 and differ from those required of other ordinary applicants (i.e. it is not necessary to provide health insurance and proof of socio-economic status).

I believe that this should excuse you from the requirement to obtain the *nulla osta.*

Sharp-eyed readers will notice that the quoted text applies to "family members of an EU citizen," and that this would normally exclude family members of an Italian citizen with respect to Italy.  However, the title of the document is *Family members of an Italian citizen or of a citizen of another EU Country,* which is in line with the Italian law that provides for family members of Italian citizens to receive [the same consideration](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/79433/19400) that is given to the family member of other EU citizens.

Answer (score 0):

It’s impossible to give a definitive answer. The end-to-end processing timescale will depend on variables related to the personal circumstances of the applicant and their Italian spouse, such as the time needed to gather the required documentation, available appointment slots etc.

In general terms, it can take up to a year before the non-EU applicant can join their spouse in Italy,  Obtaining a Nulla Osta, a pre-requisite to applying for the visa itself, can take from 4 to 12 months. The visa processing time is typically around three weeks, up to a couple of months, depending on where the application is made and whether any queries are raised.

Source: https://visaguide.world/europe/italy-visa/long-stay/family/

Comment: The linked page applies to "a non-EU national living in Italy with a valid residence permit" (from the first sentence).