# Marrying an EEA national on a standard UK visitor visa

Tags: immigration, uk-visa, marriage, italy

If I go to UK on visitor visa, am I allowed to marry an EEA national and apply for a residence card?

Comment: You have tagged Italy & UK.  Where do you want to reside?  What is your nationality?  Are you currently a resident in the EEA?  Is your to be spouse already living in the UK?  What is their residence status?

Comment: He comes and goes to UK, we are not yett

Comment: married he lives permanently in italy , if i have schengen visa can i get married in Italy

Comment: but can we marry in UK and apply for residence card

Comment: Please update the question to provide all the required details in a clear and concise manner.

Comment: Have you been living with your fiance (in Italy or elsewhere)?  If so, for how long?

Comment: What is the nationality of your fiance?

Answer (score 2):

No, if the purpose of your visit to the UK is explicitly to marry and settle.  https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa

Visitors who have entered the UK as a genuine visitor and subsequently wish to marry or form a civil partnership can give notice  https://www.gov.uk/marriages-civil-partnerships/give-notice of their intention to marry at their local register office but the immigration authorities at the Home Office will be told.

The Home Office might:

- ask questions about you and your relationship - if this happens you may need to wait up to 70 days before getting married or forming a civil partnership
- decide not to approve your notice - if this happens you cannot get married or form a civil partnership in the UK

Source: https://www.gov.uk/marriages-civil-partnerships

For a detailed description of the steps required to marry in England and Wales, see https://www.citizensadvice.org.uk/family/living-together-marriage-and-civil-partnership/getting-married/ and for Scotland see https://www.nrscotland.gov.uk/registration/getting-married-in-scotland/how-do-i-go-about-it

For you to get a residence permit in the UK after your marriage, your Italian spouse would need to be exercising his freedom of movement rights to live in the UK. There is a brief overview of what this means during the post-Brexit transition period here https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-49973387

Comment: There is also a visa which allows you to travel to the UK to get married and stay as a visitor for up to 6 months.

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith I doubt the OP is eligible for the MVV if the explicit intention at the time of application is to stay in the UK after marriage https://www.gov.uk/marriage-visa

Comment: Maybe not, although the OP is a bit vague about their circumstances.  But also worth noting for others in the future who may come across the post for whom it may be more applicable.

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith From previous questions https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/20158/how-much-time-it-takes-to-get-italian-spouse-visa and https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/20209/if-i-have-a-uk-residence-card-can-i-move-to-italy it seems the OP is marrying an Italian citizen who lives in Italy